# Get XYZ list from Raster object

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I know that for getting a raster from and XYZ list (where x and y are numeric vectors of coords and z is a numeric matrix) I can use directly the function `raster`. But what if I have a raster and I want to get an XYZ list? Is there a simple function already developed on the raster package?

Of course, I know that I can build a list indexing the different levels on the raster object, but I found that I have to make some reversions to achieve it, so I wonder to know if there is a simple and efficient way.

Thanks.

Comment: this should work: `df <- as.data.frame(myrast, xy=TRUE)`

Comment: @LoBu, I was talking about to have as output a list with 3 levels: 

output (a list)
 $x (numeric vector, longitudes)
 $y (numeric vector, latitudes)
 $z (numeric matrix with length(x) rows and length(y) cols)

Comment: Hi. sorry but I don't know if I follow you right: you want latitudes and longitudues as vectors and the image as matrix ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may consider using `rasterToPoints`:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster()
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)

xyz <- rasterToPoints(r)

head(xyz)
           x    y layer
#[1,] -179.5 89.5     1
#[2,] -178.5 89.5     2
#[3,] -177.5 89.5     3
#[4,] -176.5 89.5     4
#[5,] -175.5 89.5     5
#[6,] -174.5 89.5     6
```

But note that the function only returns values for cells that are not `NA`
And that this returns a single matrix; not a list. But this may be more practical. Otherwise see @Val's solution...

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of ways to do it, but this seems to be straight forward to me:

Essentially you use the function `xyFromCell` from the `raster` package to get the coordinates of the cells, and then you'll bind it together to your desired list.

```
library(raster)

# testraster
r <- raster()
r[] <- runif(ncell(r))

#coordinates
coords <- xyFromCell(r,1:ncell(r))

#create list
xyzlist <- list(x=coords[,'x'],y=coords[,'y'],z=as.matrix(r))
```

Which gives you:

```
> str(xyzlist)
List of 3
 $ x: num [1:64800] -180 -178 -178 -176 -176 ...
 $ y: num [1:64800] 89.5 89.5 89.5 89.5 89.5 89.5 89.5 89.5 89.5 89.5 ...
 $ z: num [1:180, 1:360] 0.786 0.867 0.0361 0.0605 0.7276 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above suggestions, but didn't quite get the  answer wanted. So, here is a small tweak and test that it works:

```
library(raster) 
xy <- xyFromCell(dem,1:ncell(dem))

lns <- contourLines(x=sort(unique(xy[,1])), y=sort(unique(xy[,2])), z=t(as.matrix(dem)))

plot(dem)
for (i in 1:length(lns)) lines(lns[[i]]$x, lns[[i]]$y)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Answers with only code in them tend to get flagged for deletion as they are "low quality".  Please read the help section on answering questions then consider adding some commentary to your Answer.